# how to check the contents/properties inside error?

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var txt="";
function message()
{
try
  {
  adddlert("Welcome guest!");
  }
catch(err)
  {
  console.log(err);
  txt="There was an error on this page.\n\n";
  txt+="Error description: " + err.message + "\n\n";
  txt+="Click OK to continue.\n\n";
  console.log(txt);
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" value="View message" onclick="message()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Question:

I want to check the contents(e.g.`err.message`) inside `error`, so I put this line: `console.log(err);` in chromo->console, it `shows:ReferenceError {}` so my question is:
How could I check the contents/properties inside `error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question. You are asking for error properties right:

```
for(var propertyName in err) {
   console.log(propertyName + ": " + err[propertyName]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put a breakpoint in that location(inside the catch block) using the browser developer tool and then inspect the variable

Or add a `debugger;`([debugger](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/debugger)) statement in the catch block so that the browser debugger will get activated at that location

```
debugger;
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gHfKG/)

Answer (score 0):

There are other console methods that can help you out. Read the api reference to learn more.

**[`console.dir(object)`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console-api#consoledirobject)**

> Prints a JavaScript representation of the specified object. If the object being logged is an HTML element, then the properties of its DOM representation are displayed.

With this code

```
try  {
  adddlert("Welcome guest!");
} catch(err) {
  console.dir(err);
}
```

it will log the object to the console. When you expand the object in the console, you would see this screenshot below

[image: ScreenShot of Chrome Console]

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tn75/)